# javascript string remove a character at position X and add to start

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a string and a number:

```
var str='Thisisabigstring';
var numb=7;
```

I'm trying to remove the character at position `'numb'` from the string and then put it at the beginning of the string.

Trying for output like:

```
'aThisisbigstring';
```

How can I do this with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty :)

```
var b = str.charAt(numb - 1) + str.substring(0, numb - 1) + str.substring(numb);
```

Comment: @David19801 I don't know why you picked this answer since the result is wrong. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: yeah, two correct answers out of seven... a bit too low for SO.

Comment: I tried it and did not notice it was not removing the character...I have corrected and still like this answer for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "Thisisabigstring";
var numb=7;
var c = str.charAt(numb);
str = c + str.substr(0, numb) + str.substr(numb + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var s = "Thisisabigstring";
var index = 7;
var x = s.charAt(index) + s.substr(0, (index - 1)) + s.substr(index + 1);
alert(x);
```

Comment: You are removing two characters there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to convert a string to an `Array` when doing things like this:

```
str = str.split('');
str.unshift(str.splice(numb - 1, 1));
str = str.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in javascript which do that. Try this :

```
String.prototype.replaceCharAt=function(index, char){return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index+char.length);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var testStr = your_Test_string;
var CharPosition = Ur_Char_Position;
var pullOutChar = testStr.charAt(CharPosition);
testStr = pullOutChar + str.substr(0, CharPosition) + str.substr(CharPosition + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = str.substring(7,8);
str = x + str;
```